# Find the index of the longest array in an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

If you have an array containing an indefinite amount of arrays

ex:

```
var masterArray = [ [1,2,3,4,5],
                    [1,2], 
                    [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,4,4],
                    [1,2,3,4,5] ];
```

What is an efficient way to find the index of the longest array in masterArray? (in this example index would be 2).

Comment: Efficient in what way?

Comment: I should have been more clear on that. I just meant in a concise way, nothing about memory efficiency

Comment: What do you expect to happen in case of multiple arrays with maximum length?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

One-liner is:

```
masterArray
  .map(a=>a.length)
  .indexOf(Math.max(...masterArray.map(a=>a.length)));
```

But better to cache `masterArray.map(a=>a.length)` results.

```
const lengths = masterArray.map(a=>a.length);
lengths.indexOf(Math.max(...lengths));
```

Note, this code still iterate array at least* 3 times(`map`, `max`, `indexOf` separately).

**Spread operator is for readability and can be omitted*

---

For more efficiency you should manual iterate array.

```
let max = -Infinity;
let index = -1;
masterArray.forEach(function(a, i){
  if (a.length > max) {
    max = a.length;
    index = i;
  }
});
```

---

`Reduce` method:

```
masterArray.reduce((maxI,el,i,arr) => 
    (el.length>arr[maxI].length) ? i : maxI, 0);
```

Answer (score 16):

`.reduce` is the nicest way to do this:

```
masterArray.reduce(function (pending, cur, index, ar) { ar[ pending ].length > cur.length ? pending : index }, 0);
```

Or with ES6:

```
masterArray.reduce((p, c, i, a) => a[p].length > c.length ? p : i, 0);
```

Comment: condition would be `a[p].length > c.length ? p : i`

Comment: This is the most elegant answer I have seen for this question.

Comment: Yeah this is a much nicer answer. Could even ditch the index usage for a direct reference. `collection.reduce((a, b) => (a.length > b.length ? a : b),[]);`

Comment: It's nice but it doesn't work if one of your arrays is empty

Answer (score 6):

A reducer iterates the array of arrays, where the accumulator represents the index of the longest array, starting with index `0`.

For each iteration, the current item's (*array*) `length` is compared to the `length` of the currently longest array found (`arrays[acc]`)  and **if greater**, the accumulator is set to *that* `index`.

```js
var arrays = [ 
  [1,1,1,1,1],
  [1,1], 
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],   // ⬅ The longest, which is at index 2
  [1,1,1,1],
  [1,1,1,1,1,1]
]

var indexOfLongestArray = arrays.reduce((acc, arr, idx) => {
  console.log(acc, idx, JSON.stringify([arr, arrays[acc]]))
  return arr.length > arrays[acc].length ? idx : acc
}, 0)

// print result:
console.log( "longest array is at index: ", indexOfLongestArray )
```

### Short function:

```js
var indexOfLongestArray = list => list.reduce((a, arr, idx) => 
  arr.length > arrays[a].length ? idx : a
, 0)
```

Comment: `idx + 1` looks too suspicious. No way it is correct =)

Comment: @vp_arth - yep :) I don't remember why I wrote it like that, *but* I **re-wrote** the answer after your comment. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 3):

```js
masterArray.reduce(function(a,i,ii){
  if (ii === 1){
    return a
  };
  if (i.length > a.length){
    return i
  }
  return a
})
```

Comment: This returns the longest array, not its index.

Answer (score 1):

Sort a list of indexes by length in descending order, and take the first one:

```
a.map((e, i) => i) . sort((i, j) => a[j].length - a[i].length) [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all entries of the outer array using a `for` loop and compare the length of each of its items to the longest array you have found so far.

The following function returns the index of the longest array or `-1` if the array is empty.

```js
function indexOfLongest(arrays) {
  var longest = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
    if (longest == -1 || arrays[i].length > arrays[longest].length) {
      longest = i;
    }
  }
  return longest;
}  

var masterArray = [ [1,2,3,4,5],
                    [1,2], 
                    [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,4,4],
                    [1,2,3,4,5] ];
document.write(indexOfLongest(masterArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash:

```
_.max(_.map(masterArray, function(v, k) { return { id: k, size: v.length }; }),'size').id;
```

This creates a new array with objects having 'id' and 'size', then finds the maximum size in that array, and returns its 'id'.

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/8xo5ywbc/

Comment: I like @Downgoat's solution better.

Answer (score 0):

using lodash `_.maxBy`

```js
let a = [[1,2,3,4],[1,3,2,33,3,3,3,32,2,3,31,1],[1]]
console.log(_.maxBy(a, i=>i.length))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `while` loop

```js
var masterArray = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [1, 2],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
];

var i = 0, len = masterArray.length;

while (i < len) {
  // if array[i + 1] exists
  // and array[i + 1] length greater than array[i] length
  // and i + 1 equals array length - 1
  // break
  if (masterArray[i + 1] 
      && masterArray[i + 1].length < masterArray[i].length 
      && i + 1 === len - 1) {
    break
  } 
  // else increment i
  else {
    ++i
  }
}

console.log(masterArray[i])
```

Answer (score -1):

an elementary and didactic solution

```
var masterArray = [ [1,2,3,4,5],
                    [1,2], 
                    [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,4,4],
                    [1,2,3,4,5] ];

let maxIndex = -1
let currMax = 0;

for (const i in masterArray) {
   if (masterArray[i].length > currMax) {
     currMax = masterArray[i].length
     maxIndex = i
   }
}

console.log(maxIndex)
```