# Issues using setValues function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I keep getting an error message when using the `setValues()` function to export an array to Google sheets. I have tried many different methods for creating my 2D array, but I still keep getting the same errors. Sometimes my code will run (the array will export to the spreadsheet) but I will still get an error.

I originally used the `setValue()` function in a for loop but the code would time out because it ran too long. So I tried dumping all my data into a 2D Array and feeding that to the spreadsheet all at once.

Tried creating the Array as an empty 2D array

```
  var outputArray = [[]]
```

and using `.push` to populate the data into it

Tried creating the empty Array using the function:

```
function create2DArray(rows) {
  var arr = [];

  for (var i=0;i<rows;i++) {
     arr[i] = [];
  }

  return arr;
}
```

and adding the data in by rows (inside of a for loop that iterates by rowNumber)

```
outputArray[rowNumber] = [data1, data2, data3,...]
```

Used the same function above for creating empty array and created intermediate array and then put that into output array

```
outputArrayIntermediate[0] = data1;
outputArrayIntermediate[1] = data2;
outputArrayIntermediate[2] = data3;
outputArrayIntermediate[3] = data4;...

outputArray[rowNumber] = outputArrayIntermediate;
```

Here is where the error keeps happening

```
var setRows = outputArray.length;
 var setColumns = outputArray[0].length

  revenueSheet.getRange(2,1,setRows,setColumns).setValues(outputArray);
```

When I include the setColumns variable I get the error:
"The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 0 but the range has 11." 
This will still populate the data to the spreadsheet.

When I do not include the setColumns variable I get the error:
"The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 11 but the range has 1."

Comment: So the problem is how you are constructing the 2D array. What does your array look like right before setValues()? `Logger.log(outputArray);` Menu 'View' > Logs

Comment: The output array is currently of this form: [[data1, data2, data3, data4, data5...],[data1.1, data2.1, data3.1, data4.1, data5.1...],...

Comment: I have submitted an answer based on your reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there ever an instance where one row has more columns than another row? For instance if 'row' 1 in your data as 5 columns (`outputArray.length` = 5) and row 2 has 6, then the data needs a range with 6 columns.

If this is the case, here are **some solutions** in order of simplicity:

**1.** If there is no important data to the right of where you are inserting you data you can use `revenueSheet.getMaxColumns()` in your `.getRange().setValues()`.

**2.** Iterate through the data set to find the row with the longest length and set that as the number of columns. To do this see  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33577421/1691677) for a few options.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me figure it out. I couldn't see it on my logger because my array was too long, but the last row of my array was empty. When I initialized my empty array I had made it one row too long.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

You only need [] not [[]], because you are pushing arrays into outputArray, and push makes sure it will always expand when needed.

Try this:

```
outputArray = [];
outputArray.push([data1, data2, data3]);
outputArray.push([data4, data5, data6]);     

revenueSheet.getRange(2,1,outputArray.length,outputArray[0].length).setValues(outputArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help you:

```
function createSSData(numrows,numcols) {
  var numrows=numrows || 20;
  var numcols=numcols || 20;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var values=[];
  for(var i=0;i<numrows;i++) {
    values[i]=[];
    for(var j=0;j<numcols;j++) {
      values[i].push(Utilities.formatString('row: %s,col: %s',i+1, j+1));
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```