# Google sheets scrip conditional formatting error: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a formatting script. I am stuck on some of the conditional formatting.  I need to have the column change colors depending on what value is in the cell.  My code is below. I am getting the following error:

> Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of
> rows in the range. The data has 920 but the range has 999. (line 52,
> file "Code")

```
  //Conditional Formatting for transaction status column
  var rangeA = sheet.getRange("L2:L");
  var valuesA = rangeA.getValues();
  var backgrounds = [];
  var textColorTransaction = [];
  
  for(var i = 0; i < valuesA.length; i++) { //for each row that the data is present
    var aValue = valuesA[i][0];
    if(aValue == "Declined"){ //if value = Declied
      backgrounds.push(["#F39581"]);
    } else if(aValue == "Credit"){
      backgrounds.push(["#FCE8B2"])
      textColorTransaction.push(["red"]);
    } else {
      backgrounds.push([null]); //using null will reset the background color formatting
      textColorTransaction.push([null])
      }
  }
  rangeA.setBackgrounds(backgrounds); //Set the background colors all at once for speed.
  rangeA.setFontColors(textColorTransaction);
```

Comment: Hi, interesting, not sure if this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/54719545/11746212

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation / Issue:

- You forgot to add a line to push elements to `textColorTransaction` when the first block of the `if` statement evaluates to true. Therefore, `textColorTransaction` has a **smaller** size than your range `rangeA` after the `for` loop is finished.
- That is because the `for` loop iterates until the length of the column, but you are not pushing any elements to `textColorTransaction` when the cell value is equal to `"Declined"`. As a result `textColorTransaction` ends up being smaller than the length of `valuesA`.
- Taking the full column `L` might be your goal, but you might want to consider up to the last row with content. You can replace `sheet.getRange("L2:L");` with `sheet.getRange("L2:L"+sheet.getLastRow());`. This is an optional step and therefore it is not included in my solution.

### Solution:

```
  var rangeA = sheet.getRange("L2:L");
  var valuesA = rangeA.getValues();
  var backgrounds = [];
  var textColorTransaction = [];
  
  
  for(var i = 0; i < valuesA.length; i++) { //for each row that the data is present
    var aValue = valuesA[i][0];
    if(aValue == "Declined"){ //if value = Declied
      backgrounds.push(["#F39581"]);
      textColorTransaction.push(["yellow"]); // <- NEW CODE ADDED
    } else if(aValue == "Credit"){
      backgrounds.push(["#FCE8B2"])
      textColorTransaction.push(["red"]);
    } else {
      backgrounds.push([null]); //using null will reset the background color formatting
      textColorTransaction.push([null])
      }
  }
  rangeA.setBackgrounds(backgrounds); //Set the background colors all at once for speed.
  rangeA.setFontColors(textColorTransaction);
```